# Not operator in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, not-operator

What was the replacement for ***System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Not(predicate)*** in `Datatable`.

I have a filter string and that need to be applied to the source as inverse. So I would like to have a Not operator here.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: `columnFilterString = "(ISNULL([CustomerName],'Null Column') <> 'David' AND ISNULL([CustomerName],'Null Column') <> 'Jerald')" `

Comment: this need to be reverse and apply to the source.

Comment: I think there were a NOT operator that you can use to invert a boolean expression. try:
`columnFilterString = "NOT(ISNULL([CustomerName],'Null Column') <> 'David' AND ISNULL([CustomerName],'Null Column') <> 'Jerald')"`